# Brew install opencv failed at [44%]?

Tags: linux, opencv, homebrew, linuxbrew

I am bumped into one intractable issue when I install `opencv` using linuxbrew.

Below is the error information, I googled it but found nothing works.

```
[ 44%] Built target opencv_features2d  
[ 44%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_objdetect.so  
cd /tmp/opencv-20160725-28945-vyl9j5/opencv-2.4.13/macbuild/modules/objdetect && /home/usrname/.linuxbrew/Cellar/cmake/3.6.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/opencv_objdetect.dir/link.txt --verbose=1  
/usr/bin/g++-5  -fPIC -Os -w -pipe -march=native    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -  Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-  security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -  Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-  template-args -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-aggressive-loop-optimizations -fdiagnostics-  show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -  ffunction-sections -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG  -L/home/usrname/.linuxbrew/lib -Wl,--  dynamic-linker=/home/usrname/.linuxbrew/lib/ld.so -Wl,-  rpath,/home/usrname/.linuxbrew/lib -shared -Wl,-  soname,libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4 -o ../../lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4.13   CMakeFiles/opencv_objdetect.dir/src/cascadedetect.cpp.o   CMakeFiles/opencv_objdetect.dir/src/datamatrix.cpp.o   CMakeFiles/opencv_objdetect.dir/src/distancetransform.cpp.o   CMakeFiles/opencv_objdetect.dir/src/featurepyramid.cpp.o   CMakeFiles/opencv_objdetect.dir/src/fft.cpp.o   CMakeFiles/opencv_objdetect.dir/src/haar.cpp.o   CMakeFiles/opencv_objdetect.dir/src/hog.cpp.o    CMakeFiles/opencv_objdetect.dir/src/latentsvm.cpp.o   CMakeFiles/opencv_objdetect.dir/src/latentsvmdetector.cpp.o   CMakeFiles/opencv_objdetect.dir/src/linemod.cpp.o   CMakeFiles/opencv_objdetect.dir/src/lsvmparser.cpp.o   CMakeFiles/opencv_objdetect.dir/src/lsvmtbbversion.cpp.o   CMakeFiles/opencv_objdetect.dir/src/matching.cpp.o    CMakeFiles/opencv_objdetect.dir/src/objdetect_init.cpp.o   CMakeFiles/opencv_objdetect.dir/src/resizeimg.cpp.o    CMakeFiles/opencv_objdetect.dir/src/routine.cpp.o   ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.13 -ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt   ../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.13 ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.13 -ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt -Wl,-rpath,/home/usrname/.linuxbrew/Cellar/opencv/2.4.13/lib   
cd /tmp/opencv-20160725-28945-vyl9j5/opencv-2.4.13/macbuild/modules/objdetect && /home/usrname/.linuxbrew/Cellar/cmake/3.6.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_symlink_library ../../lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4.13 ../../lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4   ../../lib/libopencv_objdetect.so  
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/opencv-20160725-28945-vyl9j5/opencv-2.4.13/macbuild'   
[ 44%] Built target opencv_objdetect  
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/opencv-20160725-28945-vyl9j5/opencv-2.4.13/macbuild'  
make: *** [Makefile:164: all] Error 2

READ THIS: https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew):
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues

These open issues may also help:
```

That's all.

Comment: Is the build happening in multiple threads? Because I don't see any error logs here. And it's possible it got lost because multiple jobs were running for the build.

Comment: Btw, this is new to me. Usually people who move from linux to mac, use brew. On linux, it's more common to stick with apt-get, yum, etc..

Comment: I used brew install opencv --without-python to install it. And my environment is Linux arch.  The error lies at the last line of my question(in yellow patch): make: *** [Makefile:164: all] Error 2.

I am not a root user, so ..

cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/username

Comment: @vishal Linuxbrew is often more up-to-date than `apt` and friends. For example, my `apt`-installed `git` is version 2.14.1 while Linuxbrew’s is 2.19.2.